# Air mass of star

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astronomy, atmospheric-science

Hi I am having trouble visualising this problem, and also not sure why the air pressure has been mentioned either.

Here is the question:

Assume you observe the above delta-Cepheid star at an observatory
on a mountain high enough that the typical air pressure is only $60 \%$ of the
conditions at sea level. If the star is at an airmass of one, your detector registers
$10000$ counts from the star. Determine the number of counts your detector would
register if the star was positioned at a zenith distance of $60^{\circ} $ - assume the star
has not changed it's apparent magnitude between the two observations.

My visualisation of the problem.
First if I Imagen my self on a mountain then and it is 10000 count directly above me then if the star were to move by $60 ^{\circ}$ the I would have an air mass of 2, so the my dector would read 20000 counts.

But this is where my dought comes in, because it say 60% less at sea level I cant help but think im missing something.

So I then visualised my self climbing down the mountain as I am still under zenith to where the star is then I should still be reading $10000$ counts, correct? But now as the star I am now looking through a smaller angle than I did where I was on top of the mountain, but I cant see how the air pressure is effecting the count rate.

Comment: What is your detector counting? If the detected stuff behaves as light, increasing air mass reduces the counts. This should apply to particles as well unless some cascade take places, not sure about this. I do agree that the text is not so clear.

Comment: I assume it is photons it is detecting, as I understand from just using trig is that the equation to calculate the angle is give by $AM=1/cos(\theta)$. So think about it a little more the count rate at the bottom is not what I am concerned with. If I calculate the angle if I were at the bottom of the mountain I would get 30 degree, so plugging that in to the equation I am it an AM=1.2. So now I think maybe if I take 60% of that I have an AM of 0.7 so comparing that to a count rate at that altidued I make the cont rate at 60 degree angle 700 counts.

Comment: well that cant be correct, which mean I am looking at this question either in too much detail, or I am completing miss the point I say the because I have just read the following passage. "Insolation increases with altitude since the radiation passes through less air mass hence the energy absorption by the atmosphere is less." Im very confused by this question.

Comment: Probably the question is: given the response of detector is x at sea level with star at zenith,  how many photons will reach the detector when it is up to have 60% of air mass 1 and the star is at zenith distance y°.  The first cause a bigger counting,  the second less . To you to combine them (make the calcs)

Comment: Sorry I am having a hard time visualising what you are saying. Are you saying the question ask. To be honest I still dont understand how it can be an air mass of one at the top of the montain.

Comment: One is at sea level.  At the mountain you get 60 percent of it so more photons. But then the star is not more right above but at some angle so you have to account for a concomitant reduction of AM due to elevation and an increase due to the star not being at zenith

Comment: Ok so if I have understood you correct then, the 1000 counts is at the surface of the earth not at the top of the mountain. I am required to calculate the count at the top of the mountain first and calculate the angle at 60?

Comment: You basically have to find out the AM atop.  Yes they give you the counts for am 1

Comment: Ok so I applogise for all the questions, so is the airmass of the top equal to 1600 counts as it 60% less than the surface but how can u calulte the count rate at 60 degree he would have to be less that that using equation i stated perivous I have an airmass of 2 but I cant see how that relates to the 1600

Comment: You should get 14000 counts atop because there is 0.6 am between the detector and the star at zenith. However from this point you apply AM formula which is just trigonometry as for the star is not a zenith now but at zenith distance of 60 degree. I suppose it means the angle between zenith and the star is 60 deg. Therefore the final requested count will be less than 14000 because there is again more air between the  detector and the star.  I assume you know the formula and definition of am as well as pitagoraen stuff. I am working with lamp giving me the am I want so forgot possible subtleties

Comment: Ok so I offically make the count rate 7000 counts at 60 degree?

Comment: I would say that it makes sense

Comment: If I assume that star does not change apparent magnitude than the detector will always read 10000. What else should bee the apparent magnitude? :)) probably in astronomy app mag is defined at AM0. Stop.  My last on this.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, im not sure how the detector remain the same if apparent mag is the same as surely the atmosphere as you mention will decrease the amount of photon energy getting to the dector

Answer (score 1):

The question cannot be answered as written; it lacks required information - namely the extinction per airmass at whatever wavelength you are observing.

If you knew that, then indeed observing at a zenith distance of 60 degrees increases the airmass by a factor of $\sec z = 2$ and there would be twice as much extinction and the detected counts would *decrease* accordingly.

An alternative piece of information would be to tell you how many counts are detected at sea level. That is because the total airmass above you is proportional to the pressure. So if you are on the top of the mountain you are actually observing through 0.6 of a sea-level airmass at zenith. Thus the difference between the counts at sea level and the counts at zenith on top of the mountain would give you the extinction caused by 0.4 of a sea level airmass.